# operation of for loop

Tags: c

i am working in embedded c for last some month and till now i have come across simple for loops like:

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
```

but now i came across a new type of for loop which is:

```
for(t=0; string[t]; ++t)
```

can anyone please tell me how this loop works.
The sample code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void print_upper(char *string);

int main(void)
{
    char s[80];
    printf("Enter a string: ");
    gets(s);
    print_upper(s);
    printf(''\ns is now uppercase: %s", s);
    return 0;
}

/* Print a string in uppercase. */
void print_upper(char *string)
{
    register int t;
    for(t=0; string[t]; ++t)
    {
        string[t] = toupper(string[t]);
        putchar(string[t]);
    }
}
```

Comment: A couple of tips. 1: Proof-read your submission. If it looks terrible, fix it. 2: Read the very obvious "How to format" instructions.

Comment: @ JOE OK bro i will read the format instrucy=tions and thanks a LOT FOR UR ANSWER

Comment: No problem Bill. Hot tip: IBM are looking for an operating system for their new "PC".

Comment: Note: the print_upper function has side-effects. Not only does it print the string in upper case, it also converts the string to upper case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the string is null-terminated, then the last character will be a null. This evaluates as false. The middle clause of the for syntax is a boolean expression. If it is true, the loop continues, if it is false, the loop terminates. The loop indexes character `t` of the string, and increments `t`, meaning that it tests each character in turn to see if it is 'true'.

This syntax would therefore loop over every character in the string and stop at the end.

Comment: ....and of course, it fails terribly if the ending null is missing.  #2 cause of buffer overrruns.

Comment: More of a failing of null-terminated strings. I don't think you could write a string iterator that does cope with this case... could you?

Comment: only if the buffer size is known, change the condition to `t<BUFSIZE && string[t]`

Comment: Calling a character buffer in C `string` implies that it is null-terminated.

Comment: Yes but sometimes it's useful to spell things out to newcomers to a language. Documentation is a sea of terms, not all of which 'join up'. I've seen it a lot on stackoverflow, and a bit of verbosity doesn't hurt.

Answer (score 1):

the loop has 3 parts

1. `t=0;` initialization
2. `string[t];` condition to exit the loop, if string[t] is `null` which is like saying the condition is false, the loop will exit
3. `++t` incrementation, once it has made one loop, it increments t

so basically, your loop checks string char by char, once it finds the null caracter, it exits